# RubyMine 2016: Navigate from route to controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

In RubyMine 2016, is there a way to navigate from a route to a controller action? I see a friend doing something similar in PyCharm with Cmd+B but I can't make it work in RubyMine.

Also refactoring a controller action in RubyMine won't rename the name of the method in the route. PyCharm seems to work flawlessly with Python.

So I have these routes

```
root 'application#hello'
get '/goodbye' => 'application#goodbye'
```

When I position my cursor on #hello (root route) and hit Cmd+B it should go to the application_controller.rb action "hello":

```
def hello
  # render text: "Hey kumpel"
  render({:text => "Hey kumpel"})
end
```

But I get the message "Cannot find declaration to go to".

Comment: Also vim is able to do this with Tim Pope's Rails "Plugin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install [Railways](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7110) plugin. It does exactly what you want

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is not exactly the same but kind of similiar and i use it a lot.

For instance, select '`application#goodbye`' and press `Cmd + O(letter) followed by enter` that will bring you to the `applications_controller.rb`.